# Assets Field within Structure Entries

Tags: assets, structure, parse-order, related-entries

I'm running into a problem with Assets & [Structure Entries 1.3.4 & 1.2.8](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/structure-entries) — effectively it boils down to the fact that my Assets field only returns the filename, not the entire folder path.

Here's a couple of examples:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="staff"}
  {staff_photo} - returns /ee-uploads/images/staff/filename.jpg
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

That works as expected, however if I need to do this within Structure Entries:

```
{exp:structure_entries depth="1" parent="9"}
  {staff_photo} - returns filename.jpg but not the full path
  {staff_photo:url} - returns nothing just the tag
{/exp:structure_entries}
```

I've also tried adding parse inward to this tag:

```
{exp:structure_entries depth="1" parent="9" parse="inward"}
  {staff_photo} - returns filename.jpg but not the full path
  {staff_photo:url} - returns nothing just the tag
{/exp:structure_entries}
```

However I get the exact same result with or without `parse="inward"`. Does anyone have any ideas I'm really stuck here. It's worth noting that this problem doesn't arise when using the build in Structure tag of `exp:structure:entries` but I need access to the {current_page} variable available within the Structure Entries plugin as well as a couple of other features. Any help would be really appreciated at this point.

ExpressionEngine: 2.6.1 / Assets: 2.1.3 / Structure 3.3.10 / Structure Entries 1.3.4

Thanks!

EDIT:
It's worth noting that when I add the parse inward tag I do get this error:

```
  Severity: Notice

  Message: Undefined property: Assets_ft::$row

  Filename: assets/ft.assets.php

  Line Number: 1094
```

Comment: Hey Ben,

Could you ping us at support@pixelandtonic.com, preferrably with CP access (FTP as well would be perfect) so we can look into this for you?

Comment: This isn't a problem with Assets, but the way that structure_entries parses third-party fieldtypes.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is that Structure Entries doesn't parse the newer variable references (e.g. {staff_photo:url}) and it only parses EE file paths:

```
$this->EE->typography->parse_file_paths($output);
```

Alas the add-on is very old and tries to manually parse each row and each fieldtype it supports (only aimed at supporting Playa and Matrix originally).

Apologies for this suggestion as this is a fudge fix, but try

```
{exp:structure_entries depth="1" parent="9"}
  {exp:assets:files filename="{staff_photo}"}{url_huge}{/exp:assets:files}
{/exp:structure_entries}
```

Ref: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/module/files.html

Failing that:
https://github.com/rsanchez/parse_file_paths

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately using the exp:assests:files loop method doesn't work. Will have a look at my other options before trying the Parse File Paths.

Answer (score 1):

I have [added an updated version of parse_file_paths](https://github.com/terrybritton/parse_file_paths) by rsanchez as a fork which now will work in EE 3.x and up.

All I did was to add the addon.setup.php file to the zip file with the appropriate fields filled in. The original code still works like a champ!

This works very well with the Query module. It takes the raw results containing {filedir_X} and expands that into the actual file path, using a routine already in the typography.php library in EE but for some reason that is not used by the query module by default. This little addon makes up for that.

Comment: You can now see the new "parse_file_paths" in action by performing a search on this page https://ncwildflower.org/plant_galleries/all_fields_search -- the results page loads the thumbnails on the left in a loop driven by the query module getting the image paths from that plugin. (in EE 5.2.1 as of this writing)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is still stuck on this, I was able to solve this using Peter's solution, with a slight variation on the assets:files syntax:

```
{exp:structure_entries depth="1" parent="9"}
  {exp:assets:files folder="*" keywords="{staff_photo}" recursive="yes"}
    {url}
  {/exp:assets:files}
{/exp:structure_entries}
```